# Como funciona o algoritmo do Xor Swap?

Tags: c, algoritmo

Estava estudando operações bit a bit e me deparei com o algoritmo do Xor Swap. Eu entendo o que ele faz (troca o valor de duas variáveis), mas não entendo como ele faz isto, a nível de cálculo e codificação.

Segue o algoritmo em `C`:

```
void xorSwap( int *x, int *y ) {
        if ( x != y ) {
                *x ^= *y;
                *y ^= *x;
                *x ^= *y;

                /* Versão compacta: *x ^= *y ^= *x ^= *y; */
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ele é utilizado para trocar dois valores sem a necessidade de uma variável temporária, utilizando operações `xor`.

Para entendê-lo é só olhar a tabela do `xor` e analisar passo-a-passo o algoritmo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para `x = 0b1010` e `y = 0b0011`:

```
x = 0b1010 xor 0b0011; // que resulta em x = 0b1001
y = 0b1001 xor 0b0011; // usando o novo valor de x, e y = 0b1010
x = 0b1001 xor 0b1010; // Finalizando com os valores trocados.
```

---

> Deve-se considerar que essa prática é válida para sistemas antigos e\ou com pouca RAM e para otimizar o uso dos registradores. Para os sistemas atuais, o uso de uma variável temporária é mais apropriado (ou funções próprias do sistema em questão). Como é discutido [aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549155/why-swap-dont-use-xor-operation-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, vamos lembrar algumas propriedades do XOR (exclusive-OR):

- A^A = 0
- elemento neutro: A^0 = A
- comutativa: A^B = B^A
- associativa: (A^B)^C = A^(B^C)

Segue uma explicação retirada [daqui](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/xor.html):

A chave para se convencer de que isso funciona é acompanhar os valores originais de x e y. Seja A o valor original de x (isto é, o valor que x possui antes de executar essas três linhas de código). De mesma forma, seja B o valor original de y.

Podemos comentar cada linha de código para ver o que está acontecendo.

```
// x == A, y == B
x = x ^ y ;  
 // x == A ^ B, y == B
y = x ^ y ;  
 // x == A ^ B
 // y == (A ^ B) ^ B == A ^ (B ^ B)  (por associatividade)
 //   == A ^ 0  (devido à propriedade z ^ z == 0)
 //   == A      (devido à propriedade z ^ 0 == z)
x = x ^ y ;
 // x == ( A ^ B ) ^ A
 //   == ( A ^ A ) ^ B  (por associatividade/comutatividade)
 //   == 0 ^ B            (devido à propriedade z ^ z == 0)
 //   == B                (devido À propriedade z ^ 0 == z)
 // y == A
```

Depois que o segundo *statement* executou, y = A. Depois do terceiro *statement*, x = B.

Answer (score 3):

O que a [operação de disjunção exclusiva (XOR)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_exclusiva) faz é o seguinte:

Digamos que tenhamos uma variável X e Y. Quando eu faço um `XOR` entre X e Y, o que acontece é, quando os valores são diferentes, retorna-se um bit verdadeiro, quando são iguais retorna-se um bit falso.

No [algoritmo XOR swap](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_XOR_Swap), o que se faz é:

1. Criar um "negativo" da variável X em relação a Y;
2. Faze-se um XOR desse negativo com Y, o que retorna o valor de X;
3. Faze-se um XOR entre o valor original de X (agora em Y) com o "negativo" de X, o que retorna o valor original de Y.

Se for utilizado como exemplo os valores `x = 12` e `y = 10` (como no exemplo do link), teremos:

```
x = 1100 / y = 1010
x = x XOR y
x = 0110 / y = 1010
y = y XOR x
x = 0110 / y = 1100
x = x XOR y
x = 1010 / y = 1100
```

Basicamente, essa é uma das [propriedades da disjunção exclusiva](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_exclusiva#Propriedades).