# Inverter um número de 3 dígitos em C

Tags: c, string, algoritmo

Necessito fazer um programa que o usuário digite um número de três dígitos e o programa inverte esse numero por exemplo `123 -> 321`, gostaria de saber a lógica para fazer isso, pois não consigo pensar em algo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se quiser entender como funciona o algoritmo de uma função que faça a reversão:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char str[]) {
    int len = strlen(str) ;
    char tmp;
    for (int i = len / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i - 1];
        str[len - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "123";
    reverse(str);
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2rr2yi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/quvwkvvs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ReverseNumber.c).

Fazendo por matemática:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int reverse(int num) {
    int inv = 0;
    int dig = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        dig = num / (int)pow(10.0, (double)i); //infelizmente C não tem uma função de potência para inteiro
        num -= dig * (int)pow(10.0, (double)i);
        inv += dig * (int)pow(10.0, (double)(2 - i));
    }
    return inv;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", reverse(123));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aOSrTn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ufyedmqv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ReverseNumberMath.c).

Answer (score 8):

Se voce precisar de um funcao que faca a inversao de numeros de tamanho arbitrario:

```
int inverte(int x) {
    int inv = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        inv = 10 * inv + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return inv;
}
```

O que ela faz e ir pegando o resto da divisao do numero por 10, ou seja, o digito mais a direita do numero e somar com o numero que temos ate o momento vezes 10.

Por exemplo, se formos inverter 23:

```
inv = 0
resto de 23 por 10 == 3
inv = 10 * inv + 3 == 3
dividimos 23 por 10 == 2
repetimos:
inv = 10 * inv + 2 % 10 == 10 * 3 + 2 == 32
```

Comment: Eu estava fazendo por cálculo, devia ter pensando em usar o módulo  para evitar a função de potência.

Comment: Tragam um oscar pra esse mito! Estava matutando sobre como fazer isso com tamanhos dinâmicos. Seu exemplo foi bem mais simples do que estava pensando em fazer, muito obrigado Lucas, ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 6):

Para as condições exatas do problema, basta isso:

```
str[0] ^= str[2];
str[2] ^= str[0];
str[0] ^= str[2];
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/vxC2Th)**

### Versão inline :)

```
str[0] ^= str[2] ^= str[0] ^= str[2];
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/DbRSBl)**

### Aplicando a strings de tamanho maior:

```
int i, len = strlen( str );
for ( i = len / 2; i >= 0; i--)
    str[i] ^= str[len - i - 1] ^= str[i] ^= str[len - i - 1];
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GQxMLQ)**

<sub>Postei como "curiosidade algoritmica", já que as duas soluções postadas resolvem bem o problema, da maneira tradicional.</sub>
<sub>Para saber como funciona esta solução, veja **[esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9497/70)**. (dica do  @bfavaretto)</sub>

Comment: Essa é legal p/ quem é mais *hardcore*. Provavelmente teria alguns benefícios usando assim.

Answer (score -3):

Para esse problema com 3 dígitos isso já basta.

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
    int n = 123;
    cout << "Valor inicial:" << n << endl;
    cout << "Valor Inverso:";
    cout << n % 100 % 10 / 1;
    cout << n % 100 / 10;
    cout << n / 100;
   }
```

Comment: Por que nessa linha `cout << n % 100 % 10 / 1;` você divide por 1 ? Veja https://ideone.com/SqpLvD

Comment: Nessa mesma linha, `n % 100 % 10` é equivalente a `n % 10`, não se faz necessário primeiro pegar o resto da divisão por 100 para, então pegar o resto da divisão por 10. Aproveitando, esta presente questão é sobre [tag:c] e sua resposta está em [tag:C++], creio que deixar explícito no texto da resposta que você está dando o exemplo em outra linguagem pode ajudar quem chegar aqui no futuro a não se confundir

Answer (score -3):

Esse função funciona para números positivos e negativos

```
int foo(int num) {
    int x = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    
    if(num < 0) {
        flag = true;
        num = num * -1;
    }
    
    while (num > 9) {
        x = x + num % 10;
        x = x * 10;
        num = num / 10;
        
        if (num < 10) {
            x = x + num;
        }
        
    }
return flag ? x*-1 : x;
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).