# O que são os operadores lógicos e como funciona as operações bit-a-bit na linguagem C?

Tags: c, memória, operadores, bit

O que são os operadores lógicos `NOT`, `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`, em linguagem `C`?

Também não compreendi estes operadores: `~`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `>>`, `<<` e o resultado em bits. Tenho o seguinte exemplo de código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned char x, y;
   x = 44;
   printf("x = %d\n", x);
   y = ~x;
   printf("~x = %d\n", y);
   y = x & 67;
   printf("x & 67 = %d\n", y);
   y = x | 129;
   printf("x | 129 = %d\n", y);
   y = x ^167;
   printf("x ^167 = %d\n", y);
   y = x <<2;
   printf("x <<2 = %d\n", y);
   y = x >>2;
   printf("x >>2 = %d\n", y);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acho que não...

Comment: @user24857 se não é duplicata, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63215/edit) sua pergunta e explique quais são suas dúvidas, "não consigo entender isto" é genérico demais.

Comment: Gostaria de uma explicação, não entendi isso. Pq o resultado é ...?

Comment: Acho que ele gostaria de ter uma explicação esmiuçada de cada operador.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Operações bit a bit, operações com bits ou lógica binária, normalmente se refere a operações lógicas feitas com números binários. Essas operações variam desde operações `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, `XOR`, `NOR`, `NAND`, [simples deslocamento de bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10174/como-funciona-o-deslocamento-de-bits-em-c-c), entre outras operações. Cabe dizer que algumas dessas operações aqui citadas são agrupamentos de outras operações, como a `NAND`, que é um agrupamento de uma lógica `AND` com a lógica `NOT`. Há também coisas interessantes a serem estudadas, como Álgebra de Boole (ou [Álgebra Booleana](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_booliana)) e os [Teoremas de De Morgan](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremas_de_De_Morgan).

## **Operação NOT.**

A operação `NOT` (NÃO), também chamada de "negação" ou "inversão", é a mais simples das operações, pois consiste em inverter o estado dos bits. Tomemos como exemplo o número binário `00111100`. Após passar por uma operação `NOT` se torna `11000011`. Em algumas linguagens de programação, como `C`, se usa o operador `~` para inverter o estado dos bits. A operação `NOT` segue a tabela verdade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tomemos como exemplo o seguinte código em `C`:

```
unsigned char x, y;
x = 44;
printf("x = %d\n", x);
y = ~x;
printf("~x = %d\n", y);
```

Este trecho resulta na seguinte impressão:

```
x = 44
~x = 211
```

Você pode verificar o tamanho que uma variável ocupa em `C` através da chamada de função `sizeof(type)`. Essa função retorna o tamanho da variável em bytes, de forma que é preciso multiplicar o resultado por 8 para obter o valor em bits.

```
printf("Tamanho do char é de %d bits e %d byte (s)\n", (sizeof(char) * 8), sizeof(char));
```

Este trecho resulta na seguinte impressão:

```
Tamanho do char é de 8 bits e 1 byte (s)
```

Pelo fato do tipo char em `C` ser uma variável de 8 bits, ao fazer a atribuição de `x = 44` o que se está fazendo é atribuir uma variável que contenha o valor `00101100`. Ou melhor:

```
x = 44 é:
128| 64| 32| 16| 8| 4| 2| 1
  0|  0| 1 | 0 | 1| 1| 0| 0
```

Assim sendo, temos 32 + 8 + 4 que equivale aos 44 já mencionados. Mas quando se passa a operação `NOT`, você inverte o estado destes bits, ficando:

```
x = 44 é:
0| 0| 1| 0| 1| 1| 0| 0
y = ~x é:
1| 1| 0| 1| 0| 0| 1| 1 Equivalente a 211
```

Uma coisa que é interessante notar é que o inverso de 44 em uma variável de 8 bits é 211. Uma variável de 8 bits armazena 256 valores, sendo estes valores de 0 a 255, logo pode se dizer que ao efetuar uma negação, você obtém o valor restante aos 255 (44 + 211 = 255).

## **Operação AND.**

A operação `AND` (E), também chamada de "conjunção", tem como símbolo o `*` ou `.` e retorna 1 quando, e somente quando, todos os bits forem 1 (ou verdadeiros). Na linguagem `C` essa operação tem como símbolo o `&` entre duas variáveis. A operação `AND` (OU) é uma operação que segue a seguinte tabela verdade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tomemos agora o seguinte trecho de código:

```
y = x & 67;
printf("x & 67 = %d\n", y);
```

Este trecho resulta na seguinte impressão:

```
x & 67 = 0
```

`x` ainda equivale a 44, ou seja `00101100` em binário. Ao efetuar uma operação `AND` com 67 (`01000011` em binário) o que na verdade está se fazendo é:

```
MSB (Most Significant Bit)
x  & 67
0 AND 0 => 0
0 AND 1 => 0
1 AND 0 => 0
0 AND 0 => 0
1 AND 0 => 0
1 AND 0 => 0
0 AND 1 => 0
0 AND 1 => 0
LSB (Least Significant Bit)

00000000 binário => 0 decimal
```

Portanto, uma operação `AND` entre `44 & 67` retorna o número 0, impresso na linha seguinte.

## **Operação OR.**

A operação `OR` (OU), também chamada de "disjunção", tem como símbolo o `+`. Esta operação retorna 1 quando qualquer um dos bits for 1 e retorna 0 quando TODOS os bits forem 0. A operação `OR` é uma operação que segue a seguinte tabela verdade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na linguagem C, usa-se o operador `|` para efetuar uma operação OR entre duas variáveis. Como no seguinte código:

```
y = x | 129;
printf("x | 129 = %d\n", y);
```

Este trecho resulta na seguinte impressão:

```
x | 129 = 173
```

`x` que vale `44`, ou seja `00101100` em binário, está em uma operação de disjução com `129` (`10000001` em binário). Ao efetuar uma operação `OR` entre `44` e `129` o que na verdade está se fazendo é:

```
MSB (Most Significant Bit)
x & 67
0 OR 1 => 1
0 OR 0 => 0
1 OR 0 => 1
0 OR 0 => 0
1 OR 0 => 1
1 OR 0 => 1
0 OR 0 => 0
0 OR 1 => 1
LSB (Least Significant Bit)

10101101 binário => 173 decimal
```

Portanto, uma operação `OR` entre `44 & 129` retorna o número `173`, impresso na linha seguinte.

## **Operação XOR.**

A operação `XOR` (OU Exclusivo), também chamada de "disjunção exclusiva", é uma operação lógica entre dois operandos que resulta em um valor lógico verdadeiro se, e somente se, exatamente um dos operandos possui valor verdadeiro. Pode ser sintetizado como um detector de diferenças entre dois operandos lógicos. Essa operação segue a seguinte tabela verdade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A operação XOR é uma maneira interessante de se trocar o valor de duas variáveis sem precisar de uma terceira, como demonstra a excelente resposta dada por Lucas Nunes [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9497/como-funciona-o-algoritmo-do-xor-swap).

Na linguagem C, usa-se o operador `^` para efetuar uma operação `XOR` entre duas variáveis. Como no seguinte código:

```
y = x ^167;
printf("x ^167 = %d\n", y);
```

Que resulta na impressão:

```
x ^167 = 139
```

Pois `44 (00101100) XOR 167 (10100111)`:

```
MSB (Most Significant Bit)
x  ^ 167 
0 XOR 1 => 1
0 XOR 0 => 0
1 XOR 1 => 0
0 XOR 0 => 0
1 XOR 0 => 1
1 XOR 1 => 0
0 XOR 1 => 1
0 XOR 1 => 1
LSB (Least Significant Bit)

10001011 binário => 139 decimal
```

Portanto, uma operação `XOR` entre `44 & 167` retorna o número `139`, impresso na linha seguinte.

## **Deslocamento de bits.**

Na linguagem `C` usa-se os operadores `>>` ou `<<` para efetuar o deslocamento de bits entre variáveis para direita ou esquerda. O deslocamento de bits, como o nome já diz, é uma técnica de deslocar os bits para uma ou mais casas. Uma característica interessante do deslocamento de bits é que é possível multiplicar ou dividir o valor daquela variável, mas não entrarei detalhes sobre isto nesta resposta.

O deslocamento de bits funciona da seguinte forma, por exemplo, ao se deslocar uma variável x a esquerda:

```
int x = 1; // 0000 0001

int x0 = (x << 0); // 0000 0001 Não deslocado    
int x1 = (x << 1); // 0000 0010
int x2 = (x << 2); // 0000 0100
int x3 = (x << 3); // 0000 1000
int x4 = (x << 4); // 0001 0000
int x5 = (x << 5); // 0010 0000
int x6 = (x << 6); // 0100 0000
int x7 = (x << 7); // 1000 0000
```

Agora se deslocar a direita:

```
int x = 128; // 1000 0000

int x0 = (x >> 0); // 1000 0000 Não deslocado
int x1 = (x >> 1); // 0100 0000
int x2 = (x >> 2); // 0010 0000
int x3 = (x >> 3); // 0001 0000
int x4 = (x >> 4); // 0000 1000
int x5 = (x >> 5); // 0000 0100
int x6 = (x >> 6); // 0000 0010
int x7 = (x >> 7); // 0000 0001
```

Não vou me aprofundar muito nesta técnica, mas recomendo que leia a excelente resposta de Lucas Nunes [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10174/como-funciona-o-deslocamento-de-bits-em-c-c), de onde tirei o exemplo acima. Mas no caso do código que você forneceu na sua pergunta, o que acontece é:

```
y = x << 2;
printf("x <<2 = %d\n", y);
```

O trecho de código acima imprime:

```
x <<2 = 176
```

Pois:

```
00101100 em binário é 44 em decimal
00101100 << 2
01011000 //Moveu 1 bit a esquerda
10110000 //Moveu 2 bits a esquerda

10110000 em binário => 176 decimal

y = x >> 2;
printf("x >>2 = %d\n", y);
```

O trecho de código acima imprime:

```
x >>2 = 11
```

Pois:

```
00101100 em binário é 44 em decimal
00101100 >> 2
00010110 //Moveu 1 bit a direita
00001011 //Moveu 2 bits a direita

00001011 em binário => 11 decimal
```

## **Aplicações.**

Operações com bits são muito utilizadas quando se programa baixo nível. É possível configurar [registradores de microcontroladores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10174/como-funciona-o-deslocamento-de-bits-em-c-c) e fazer otimizações de código, por exemplo. Também são utilizados em [algoritmos de criptografia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43492/como-funciona-o-algoritmo-de-criptografia-aes), pois por se tratarem de operações lógicas são menos custosas ao processador. Em eletrônica digital, são utilizadas a todo momento.

Comment: Olá teria como colocar junto com a devida operação relacionada na pergunta do usuário @user24857?

Comment: Farei isto. Pode deixar que detalharei bem a resposta. ;)

Comment: Sim, mas não entendi o resultado ~x = 211 nesse operador  ~, que apenas deveria inverter os bits?

Comment: Ainda estou escrevendo sua resposta... tudo será esclarecido. Prometo.

Comment: 101100 em binário inverter dá 211, e em linguagem c como descubro o tamanho em binário?

Comment: São os dígitos ativos do número em binário. Estou adicionado mais conteúdo a pergunta, irei adicionar o porquê disto também.

Comment: Você pode usar o `sizeof(tipo da variavel)` para saber o tamanho dela em bytes. `printf(" %d", (sizeof(int) * 8))` retorna o valor em bits.

Comment: Entendi, bem explicado;

Comment: Acho que vou parar de escrever a minha resposta por aqui. Se ficou mais alguma dúvida, por favor, edite a sua pergunta ou coloque nos comentários. Espero ter ajudado.