# Qual a diferença entre os operadores lógicos NOT, AND e OR?

Tags: lógica, operador-lógico

Estou estudando álgebra booleana e sobre Portas Lógicas, e sei que esses operadores lógicos e portas lógicas são utilizados em sistemas digitais, programação e na eletrônica. Os 3 principais operadores da álgebra booleana são os operadores NOT, AND e OR.

Qual a diferença entre os operadores lógicos NOT, AND e OR? E qual a diferença entre as Portas Lógicas?

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta parece ter mais a ver com eletrônica do que com programação.

Comment: Mas porta lógica tem a ver com introdução a eletronica.

Comment: [Duplicada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63215/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-operadores-l%C3%B3gicos-e-como-funciona-as-opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-bit-a-bit-na-lingua/)

Comment: É a mesma coisa. Só que portas lógicas são implementações de hardware usando transistores e operadores lógicos são implementações via software que usam registradores do processador.

Comment: Agora que já tem resposta, você pode é prejudicar ela mais ainda, se ela fugir do que foi respondido.

Comment: Acho que é interessante para o programador entender como funcionam as portas lógicas, acredito que ter uma noção de como as coisas funcionam pode ajudar em algumas situações, muitas vezes durante a programação somos acostumados a usar muito OU e E como condicionais, e em alguns casos, a implementação de uma porta XOR pode resolver um problema que nos trava.

Comment: Na minha opinião você não deveria mudar sua pergunta. Quem faz computação geralmente tem uma matéria de Arquitetura de Computadores onde superficialmente se estuda portas lógicas. Também não acho ser duplicada. A resposta que o @Avelino deu no comentário já é uma resposta em si e deveria ser postada como tal.

Comment: Vou adicionar a diferença entre portas lógicas e operadores lógicos [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63215/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-operadores-l%C3%B3gicos-e-como-funciona-as-opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-bit-a-bit-na-lingua/)

Answer (score 8):

Do Wikipédia:

## Operadores lógicos

> AND, NAND, OR, XOR e NOT são os principais operadores lógicos, base para a construção de sistemas digitais e da Lógica proposicional, e também muito usado em linguagem de programação. Os operadores AND, NAND, OR e XOR são operadores binários, ou seja, necessitam de dois elementos, enquanto o NOT é unário. Na computação, esses elementos são normalmente variáveis binárias, cujos possíveis valores atribuídos são 0 ou 1. Porém, a lógica empregada para essas variáveis serve também para sentenças (frases) da linguagem humana, onde se esta for verdade corresponde ao valor 1, e se for falsa corresponde ao valor 0.

- AND

  Operador lógico no qual a resposta da operação é verdade (1) se ambas as variáveis de entrada forem verdade.

  ```
  x1  x2  x1 AND x2   
  0   0   0   
  0   1   0   
  1   0   0   
  1   1   1
  ```
- NAND

  Operador lógico no qual a resposta da operação é verdade (1) se pelo menos uma das variáveis é falsa.

  ```
  x1  x2  x1 NAND x2  
  0   0   1   
  0   1   1   
  1   0   1   
  1   1   0
  ```
- OR

  Operador lógico no qual a resposta da operação é verdade (1) se pelo menos uma das variáveis de entrada for verdade.

  ```
  x1  x2  x1 OR x2    
  0   0   0   
  0   1   1   
  1   0   1   
  1   1   1
  ```
- XOR

  Operador lógico no qual a resposta da operação é verdade (1) quando as variáveis assumirem valores diferentes entre si.

  ```
  x1  x2  x1 XOR x2   
  0   0   0   
  0   1   1   
  1   0   1   
  1   1   0
  ```
- NOT

  Operador lógico que representa a negação (inverso) da variável atual. Se ela for verdade, torna-se falsa, e vice-versa

  ```
  x1  NOT x1  
  0   1   
  1   0
  ```

<sub>Fonte: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_lógico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_l%C3%B3gico)</sub>

### Porta lógica

Acho esse assunto off-topic, porque mesmo que tenha algum contexto semelhante a programação ainda sim não sei se é totalmente abrangente, apesar de duvidas de algorítimos serem aceitas, ainda sim a duvida não é sobre um **algorítimo especifico**, mesmo assim apenas pra entoar a diferença:

> Portas lógicas ou circuitos lógicos, são dispositivos que operam um ou mais sinais lógicos de entrada para produzir uma e somente uma saída, dependente da função implementada no circuito. São geralmente usadas em circuitos eletrônicos, por causa das situações que os sinais deste tipo de circuito podem apresentar: presença de sinal, ou "1"; e ausência de sinal, ou "0". As situações "Verdade" e "Falso" são estudadas na Lógica Matemática ou Lógica de Boole; origem do nome destas portas. O comportamento das portas lógicas é conhecido pela tabela verdade que apresenta os estados lógicos das entradas e das saídas.

- AND

  [image: AND]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   B   A AND B
  0   0   0
  0   1   0
  1   0   0
  1   1   1
  ```
- OR

  [image: OR]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   B   A OR B
  0   0   0
  0   1   1
  1   0   1
  1   1   1
  ```
- NOT

  [image: not]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   NOT A
  0   1
  1   0
  ```
- NAND

  [image: NAND]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   B   A NAND B
  0   0   1
  0   1   1
  1   0   1
  1   1   0
  ```
- NOR

  [image: NOR]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   B   A NOR B
  0   0   1
  0   1   0
  1   0   0
  1   1   0
  ```
- XOR

  [image: XOR]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   B   A XOR B
  0   0   0
  0   1   1
  1   0   1
  1   1   0
  ```
- XNOR

  [image: XNOR]

  ```
  ENTRADA SAÍDA
  A   B   A XNOR B
  0   0   1
  0   1   0
  1   0   0
  1   1   1
  ```

<sub>Fonte: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_lógica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_l%C3%B3gica)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A diferença está nas condições de verdadeiro, AND (E) retorna verdadeiro se as duas entradas forem verdadeiras, OR(OU) retorna verdadeiro se pelo menos uma das entradas for verdadeira (uma OU outra), NOT (NÃO) simplesmente inverte o resultado, ou seja, se a entrada for verdadeira ela retorna falsa e vice-versa.

Se tratando de portas lógicas, as portas tratarão os bites de entrada, por exemplo (Execute o código pra visualizar melhor):

```html
AND
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ENTRADA 1</td>
    <td>ENTRADA 2</td>
    <td>RESULTADO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<br/>

OR
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ENTRADA 1</td>
    <td>ENTRADA 2</td>
    <td>RESULTADO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<br/>
NOT
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ENTRADA 1</td>
    <td>RESULTADO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>0 (falso)</td>
    <td>1 (verdadeiro)</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Com essas portas você pode fazer algumas outras, sendo as mais comuns NAND (que retorna verdadeiro se as duas entradas forem falsas) e XOR (Ou exclusivo, que retorna verdadeiro se apenas uma das entradas for verdadeira, se as duas forem retorna falso.)