# Inverter array (vetor) sem uma função externa, 'manualmente'

Tags: c, funções, array

Amigos, eu sempre inverti vetores usando um auxiliar numa função externa(acho que o jeito padrão), contudo até pouco tempo atrás um amigo me disse que tinha um jeito de inverter vetores sem usar um auxiliar, pedi para me mostrar mas acabou que não me mostrou? Procurei na net algo feito de tal maneira e não achei nada.
Como faço isso.

```
     aux = vetor[i+8];
     vetor[i+8] = vetor[i];
     vetor[i] = aux;
```

Comment: O uso de variável auxiliar é a forma canónica de trocar o valor de 2 variáveis. As outras formas de o fazer são "artificiais". Continua a fazer com o uso de auxiliar que fazes bem (o compilador vai optimizar o código melhor que tu consegues com "truques").

Comment: pmg desculpe peguei essa função apenas para demonstrar o uso que faço dos auxiliares irei altera-lá para deixar mais clara. Quero aprender apenas para motivo que curiosidade, pode ser que nem use no dia - a -dia, mas que mal faz

Comment: Um "truque" comum para trocar o valor de 2 variáveis sem usar uma variável auxiliar é o chamado *XOR swap*. Ver, por exemplo, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9497/como-funciona-o-algoritmo-do-xor-swap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O truque está na construção do ciclo `for`, tem de contar do fim para o principio do array (vetor)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   int original[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   int count = sizeof(original) / sizeof(int); // 6, numero de elementos no array original 
   int revertido[count], i, j; // declaramos que o array revertido vai ter o mesmo numero de elementos que original

   // vamos iniciar o i em count - 1, (5 indexes dos elementos do array original) vai servir para percorrermos o original do fim para o inicio, subtraimos 1 a cada volta
   // vamos iniciar o j em 0 para podermos armazenar cada valor do original a partir do index 0 no array revertido, j vai ser cada index do array revertido
   // o loop e finalizado quando j < count (quando j for 5), iria dar o mesmo resultado se a condicao fosse i >= 0

   for (i = count-1, j = 0; j < count; i--, j++) {
      revertido[j] = original[i]; // no primeiro loop o ultimo valor do original vai ser o primeiro valor (com index 0) do array revertido, no segundo loop o penultimo do original vai ser o segundo do revertido, etc...
   }

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      printf("%d \n", revertido[i]);
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Uma vez entendida a lógica, se quiser simplificar, dá para resolver usando apenas a variável `i` no loop, e assim nem precisamos do `j`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   revertido[i] = original[count - i - 1];
}

// Se i for zero, count - i - 1 será o
// último elemento (original[6 - 0 - 1] = original[5]), se for 1, será o
// penúltimo, e assim sucessivamente.
```

Answer (score 2):

Apesar da sua pergunta ser em linguagem C, apenas como contribuição à sua pergunta, na linguagem C++ (Orientada a Objetos) podemos utilizar um método muito útil para isso e abstrair essa complexidade:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void main() {
  std::vector<int> vetor_xpto;
  //quando popular pode usar...
  std::reverse(vetor_xpto.begin(), vetor_xpto.end());
}
```

Comment: Não esquecendo se o propósito é aprendizado de lógica, minha resposta não deve ser considerada :-)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar pointers, movendo pelos endereços e fazendo as substituições. Muitos dizem que é mais lento, mas eu entendo o contrário (até porque depende de outros fatores do hardware como memória cache etc.). Você evita de usar mais espaço na memória (o dobro) apenas movendo entre os endereços. O processador poupa "baldeação" entre registradores etc. Para complementar, os programadores de estúdios grandes normalmente usam quase tudo em pointers. Porque você pode fazer até embaixadinha com os dados do seu programa. Obrigado.